# Is it possible to manipulate filename in batch?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, path

I have a script in batch that finds a filename from path.
However, I dont't need the entire filename, only the first six characters.
I thought that the following script would work, but it seems to not work with filenames.

```
set PL=%%~nG
set PL=%PL:~0,6%
```

It returns "~0,6".

Comment: is this happening inside for loop or if ?

Comment: Inside a for loop.

Comment: then you need delayed expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you confirmed that this `SET` is inside for loop you'll need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%G in (something) do (
  set PL=%%~nG
  set PL=!PL:~0,6!
  echo !PL!
)
```